# Accidentally retracted my reopen vote on my question

Tags: discussion, vote-to-open

I've voted to reopen this [question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/71946/why-does-zelenskyy-urge-nato-to-impose-a-no-fly-zone). But accidentally I retracted my vote and can't vote to reopen again. Is there any solution to vote again?

Comment: Alas I think no.

Comment: Just needs one more vote I believe anyway (I've already cast).